# Strange behavior using a space in front of $SHELL environment variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

When I use the following command, everything works as expected (a new gnome-terminal is open, the current working directory is changed and the terminal remains open):

```bsh
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'cd /';$SHELL"
#                                ↑
#                      no space character here
```

But when I use:

```bsh
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'cd /'; $SHELL"
#                                 ↑
#                           note the space
```

I can see a terminal that opens, but I can't see if the current working directory is changed  or not because the terminal it closes immediately.

My question is: why this is happening; how can be wrong if I put a space in the second case?

Comment: What is this intended to do? Also, **because** the *space* makes it a *another* command (that is, it is not an argument to "bash -c").

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I just want to understand why first command is working as I wish and second no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gnome-terminal` does its own parsing of the command given to it, using [g_shell_parse_argv](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.34/glib-Shell-related-Utilities.html#g-shell-parse-argv), which apparently doesn't consider `;` to be a word separator, so if a `;` is adjacent to a non-whitespace character, it is considered to be part of that non-whitespace character's word.

This can result in surprising behavior if the command you pass to `gnome-terminal` has shell metacharacters in it.

I used `strace` on the `gnome-terminal` process to see what it does. The first command

```
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'cd /';$SHELL"
```

results in gnome-terminal running the following command

```
execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "cd /;/bin/bash"])
```

The second command

```
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'cd /'; $SHELL"
```

results in gnome-terminal running the following command

```
execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "cd /;", "/bin/bash"])
```

That being said, you should also note that a command such as `bash -c 'cd /'` will not have a lasting effect on the working directory of any command run after it. So I think that the first command you typed got the desired result *only because of the gnome-terminal parsing misfeature*, and a more robust way of writing it would be

```
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'cd /;$SHELL'"
```

Answer (score 6):

In the first case, gnome-terminal executes

```
bash -c "cd /;/bin/bash"
```

in the second case, it runs

```
bash -c "cd /;" /bin/bash
```

The first case means "evaluate `cd /;/bin/bash`", which will cd and run an interactive shell.

The second case means "evaluate `cd /;` with `$0` set to `/bin/bash`", which will run cd and then exit.